# questions on XML/<param>tag

Tags: xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the link to the tutorial about XML/param, I cannot figure out the meaning of the first sentence of the 3 options listed below, respectively.

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param

1 **textfile="$(find pkg-name)/path/file.txt"(optional)**

The contents of the file will be read and stored as a string. The file must be locally accessible, though it is strongly recommended that you use the package-relative $(find)/file.txt syntax to specify the location.

2 **binfile="$(find pkg-name)/path/file"(optional)**
The contents of the file will be read and stored as a base64-encoded XML-RPC binary object. The file must be locally accessible, though it is strongly recommended that you use the package-relative $(find)/file.txt syntax to specify the location.

3 **command="$(find pkg-name)/exe '$(find pkg-name)/arg.txt'"(optional)**

The output of the command will be read and stored as a string. It is strongly recommended that you use the package-relative $(find)/file.txt syntax to specify file arguments. You should also quote file arguments using single quotes due to XML escaping requirements.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247273/questions-on-xml/%3Cparam%3Etag/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first option will read a *text file*, and store the contents (ie: the text in it) on the parameter server under a name that you provide.

The second option will read a *binary file*, encode the contents (ie: bytes) using [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and then store the result on the parameter server under a name that you provide.

The third option will *run a command* (ie: a program), capture the output of that command (ie: text on `stdout`) and store that on the parameter server under a name that you provide.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-05**:
Thanks, it helps!

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-08**:
btw, do you know how to deal with it? thanks!

http://answers.ros.org/question/247531/moveit_setup_assistant-cannot-launch-node-of-type-in-indigo/